# Это ССП или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

Не могу понять простую вещь: если действующее лицо одно и то же, тогда предложение не сложносочинённое и запятая не нужна? Например:

> *Вася поел(,) и ему стало весело.*

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Не могу понять простую вещь: если действующее лицо одно и то же..._ === Во второй части предложения _действующее_ лицо не Вася, а его настроение. Запятая нужна.

Comment: @slava1947, спасибо! А в моём исходном всё-таки не нужна: *Злата сейчас поела(,) и её вырвало тем же кормом и слизью*? Простите за контекст, просто меня именно это интересовало.

Comment: _Артём Луговой: А в моём исходном всё-таки не нужна._ === Ваше исходное —  _"Вася поел(,) и у него поднялось настроение"._ Запятая нужна. Но если Вы **обе** части исходного предложения преобразуете в безличные предложения, то... тогда см. § 112 п. 4: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: @slava1947: простите, исходное предложение вопроса поменял. А в предыдущем комментарии имел в виду под исходным то, которое у меня вызвало вопрос (про Злату).

Comment: @slava1947: можете сказать, нужна ли запятая в вопросе про Злату?

Comment: Первое предложение — двусоставное, второе — безличное. Можете их разделить запятой, можете — тире. Выбор за автором.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Вася поел,  и ему стало весело.***

1) Это ССП, так как здесь две предикативные основы: ***Вася поел,  стало весело.***

Нужно различать **реальный субъект действия (или состояния) и грамматическое подлежащее (если оно есть).**

Субъектом действия (состояния) в обоих случаях является Вася, но во втором предложении субъект состояния выражен местоимением в Д.п., а **грамматическое подлежащее отсутствует** (предложение односоставное безличное).

2) Если это ССП, то запятая ставится, исключением является вариант, когда простые  предложения имеют общий грамматический элемент (здесь такого нет).

3) Сравнить: ***Ему стало весело и все проблемы  представлялись несущественными.*** Здесь тоже односоставное и двусоставное предложения, но есть общее дополнение ***ему***, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что это сложносочиненное предложение, имеющее следственный оттенок значения, — запятая, безусловно, нужна.

**Вася поел** [двусоставное], **и ему стало весело** [безличное].
(Без запятой было бы такое предложение: *Вася поел и развеселился*. Или такое: *Вася поел и повеселел.*)

Вот предложение из [учебника Н. С. Валгиной](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-040.htm) :
*Ему стало досадно, и он стал барабанить в закрытую дверь ногой и шашкой* (Л. Т.)

Вот предложение из книги В. Арсеньева "По Уссурийскому краю":
*В этот день мне нездоровилось немного, и потому я не стал дожидаться ужина и лег спать.*
(Предложение в упрощенном виде есть здесь: [Сложносочиненное предложение](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/284-slognosochinennoepredlogenie.html).)

1. *Он освободил коня, и ему стало весело.*
2. *Август посмотрел на фотографии летунов с рюкзаками на животе, и ему стало весело.*

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!